# Is joinable() then join() thread-safe in std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In a `std::thread`, an exception is throw if I call `join()` and the thread is not joinable.

So I do :

```
if (thread.joinable())
  thread.join();
```

Now imagine that the thread is terminated after the `joinable()` and before the `join()` (due to thread scheduling).

Is this case possible in the worth situation ? Do I really need to use a `try` / `catch` around `join()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *thread is terminated*?  Just the thread ends, or you have another thread that shares this thread object and it terminates it?

Comment: I mean that the thread is not joinable anymore.

Comment: He says that if the thread joins somehow after `if (thread.joinable())` and before `thread.join();`

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC unless you are sharing the thread with another thread, I know of no way where it would it become not joinable anymore considering only `join` or `detach` will cause that.

Comment: I think you either didn't read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable or there's an understanding problem. In any case, can you make a sketch that somehow illustrates the order of events you're concerned about?

Comment: The two calls to `joinable()` and `join()` are not atomic in the sense that the thread might become unjoinable between the two calls. But if that can happen it means you have a design error. Only one thread should ever be interested in joining with another thread.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `joinable()` is not a property of the `std::thread` object. Its result depends on the calling context!

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC A `std::thread` is still joinable avec its termination, hence it is safe to call `join()`. It can be unsafe if another thread tries to call `join()` too (for the same thread we are calling `join()` on), which should always be avoided.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I read the implementation in Visual Studio and it's different. Joinable is : "return thr._Id != 0". But I now understand that the combination joinable() / join() is thread safe if the two calls are made from the same thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Now imagine that the thread is terminated after the joinable() and before the join() (due to thread scheduling).

If thread just terminated it does not become not joinable, `std::thread::join()` will just successfully return immediately in such case as it said in documentation for [`std::thread::joinable()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable):

> A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined
>   is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore
>   joinable.

It can become not joinable if you call `std::sthread::join()` for the same thread concurrently.

> Is this case possible in the worth situation ? Do I really need to use a try / catch around join() ?

Only if you try to call `std::thread::join()` for the same thread from multiple threads. You better avoid that and have only one thread manage others.

Comment: So is it possible for the thread to join itself automatically after its execution has been finished ?

Comment: @arnes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

Comment: @arnes it depends what you mean by "automatically". It will happen only if you do something wrong in your code - call `detach()` or `join()` in another thread by **yourself**.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Already read it but i didn't understand very well. So this sentence explains the situation `A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable`

Comment: I think there are two simple rules: You can call `join()` exactly once per started thread. You can not call `join()` on the `std::thread` instance from a thread that was started with that instance (no "self-joining", which is why I quoted the link above).

Answer (score -1):

It is not thread safe. If you have more than one thread that can call your snippet at any time, you may experience a race condition. The only real way to protect against this is by wrapping your snippet in an `std::mutex` shared by the threads calling said snippet.